# Grails 2.3.0 Tomcat process lives after Grails application is killed

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'm experiencing several very annoying issues with Grails 2.3.0, the most annoying of which is Tomcat's refusal to die when I kill my Grails app.  It doesn't seem to matter if I run my Grails app from the command line or GGTS, when I stop my Grails app Tomcat doesn't die, so the next time I try to run my Grails app I am presented with the following warning:

```
| Error Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use: JVM_Bind (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I have to go hunt down the process for Tomcat and kill it manually to release the port.

I have XAMPP installed, but the Tomcat installation that comes with XAMPP is not running.  I renamed the XMAPP Tomcat directory just to make sure.  Curiously, the XAMPP control panel shows Tomcat as started when I run my Grails app (though the stop button does not work).

Comment: How are you stopping your app? Have you tried `grails stop-app`?

Comment: I just kill it with `CTRL + C`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XAMP comes with one **Apache http server** and not a **Tomcat**, the stop button of it will not kill your Grails application. It probably show's as started because it checks if `http://localhost:8080/` is online but it not validate if the localhost is from XAMP or another server.

Trying to kill the application with the red button in `GGTS` will fail indeed, there's a JIRA ticket for this. In the mean time the correct flow is to run the `stop-app` command (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>).

Comment: Awesome, do you have a link to the JIRA issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am an impatient person, and while opening a new console and using the `stop-app` command does work, it does not work fast enough.  I made this little batch file to speed things up until this gets fixed.  This batch file will find the process that is bound to port 8080 and kill it.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":8080"') do @set netstatRslt=%%a
set pid=%netstatRslt:~-5%
taskkill /f /pid %pid%
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that your proxy settings affect 'stop-app's ability to shutdown tomcat. When you run 'run-app' grails also listens on the server port + 1 (usually 8081). Any requests to that port cause the server to shutdown. The 'stop-app' script simply makes a request to that port.

In my case I used the 'add-proxy' command to configure my proxy but I didn't add the '--noproxy=localhost' parameter. I assume that that when I ran stop-app it tried to access localhost:8081 though the proxy and failed so the server didn't shutdown. Once I added '--noproxy=localhost' to my proxy config stop-app worked fine.

It also means that when you hit Ctrl+C at the grails> prompt tomcat is shutdown.