# grails 2.3 -- java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: grails, jvm, bind

If I close the application with ctrl-c (cmd )and again run the application, I get the error:- 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind:8080

I need to manually kill the earlier process and restart again. 
Is this a problem with closing the grails applicaion with ctrl-c ?

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326188/grails-2-3-0-tomcat-process-lives-after-grails-application-is-killed).

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro for the link.grails stop-app command in another cmd window worked for me.

Comment: Glad it helped. Your appreciation carries over to the answer provider (Sergio) with an up vote. ;)

Comment: Sergio's answer is correct, but I added [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19392556/288341) with an alternative to the `stop-app` command which works a bit faster than `stop-app`.

Comment: hmmm....Arn't we supposed to run the batch file in another cmd window?